# MySQL how can I get the value of all rows with the same value once?

Tags: mysql

```
Table
--------
| col1 |
--------
|  A   |
--------
|  A   |
--------
|  A   |
--------
|  B   |
--------
|  B   |
--------
|  C   |
--------
```

How can I get values A, B, C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a distinct query can accomplish your goal.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(col1) FROM `Table`;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following select:

```
select distinct(col1) from ...
```